# AWS Cognito, required fields not showing up when creating a user

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I created a user pool and selected `email`, `phone number`, `name`, and `family name` as required fields. However, when I create a user name and family name aren't there. When I pull a list of users from the aws-sdk those fields aren't listed there either.

How do I add the required fields so that they are available when creating a user and in the listUsers sdk response?